# Wondering what the words "fraction" and "virtual" really mean in this context

Tags: word-meaning

> Facebook has added a Finnish firm that makes a fitness tracking app to its ever-increasing portfolio of purchases.
>
> Helsinki-based ProtoGeo created the Moves app that uses a smartphone's built-in sensors to track activity and calories burned.
>
> The acquisition offers the social network an entry into the burgeoning health technology market.
>
> Other recent purchases include mobile messaging firm WhatsApp and **virtual** headset maker Oculus.
>
> Facebook did not reveal how much it paid for ProtoGeo, which has fewer than 10 employees, but it is believed to be **a fraction of** the price it has paid for more high-profile firms recently.
> <sub>Source: [BBC News – Facebook buys fitness app firm](http://www.bbc.com/news/technology-27155954)</sub>

Does the word "virtual" mean particular or special or unique or perhaps artificial? All these are actually a combination of my research in dictionaries and my perception. And I think all these definitions are possible in our new world!

And my perception is that the word fraction, simply means: less than. Am I right?

Comment: http://dictionary.reverso.net/english-cobuild/for%20a%20fraction%20of%20the%20price

Answer (score 4):

You are quite close!

In the text, *"virtual headset maker Oculus"* refers to a company named *[Oculus Rift](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oculus_Rift)*, which is well-known for various virtual reality products. Here is one of their virtual reality headsets:

[image]

The word ***virtual*** in *virtual headset maker* refers to the word *virtual* in ***[virtual reality](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/american/virtual-reality)***. As you suggested, you can think of "virtual reality" as an artificial reality.

The phrase *"**a fraction of** the price it has paid for more high-profile firms recently"* means that, compared to the price it has paid (for those other firms recently), the price it paid for ProtoGeo is only a fraction. ***[Fraction](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/american/fraction)*** means "a small part or amount of something".

Comment: Good answer. It's worth calling extra attention to what you said about "virtual": it's being used as an *abbreviation* of "virtual reality". "Virtual" itself means "not real, but a close simulation"; if my bank balance is *virtually* zero, I do have some money, but not enough to matter. (Taken literally, "virtual headset maker" means they don't make *real* headsets!) A similar usage is "virtual friends". They might be very real friends, but we only have virtual social contact (over the internet).